# "no working inite found"(installing ubuntu without usb)

Tags: boot

[i cant go up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RjrWQ.jpg)

So this is my home server and i want to install normal ubuntu without useing a usb and the download stopped

Comment: Have you got physical access to the computer (where you want to install Ubuntu Server)? In that case, why not USB and what drives are available? Otherwise, how can you access the computer? ('Home server' makes me think that you have physical access.)

Comment: "install normal ubuntu" using what procedure? That's not an image of a stopped download. That's an image of a kernel panic.

Comment: This looks like your Ubuntu image is corrupted. Is this some kind of network install?

Comment: Thank you all for responding so quickly and to answer some of your questions, yes I have physical access to a computer but during the USB install, I broke 3 USB ports but recently I was able to successfully install ubuntu on the 4th USB.
Secondly, I have now tried several procedures on a number of disks with no luck
If you are asking about the procedure that does not require USB, I just partitioned my disk and installed ubuntu on one of the partitions.
Thirdly, I used several procedures, but I will take your words into consideration for future attempts. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that zx485 was right. The problem was with the Ubuntu installation that I used. For some reason, my computer was having problems with the popular Ubuntu installers, so I tried installing Ubuntu on a flash using another computer, and this solved my problem.